# Как клонировать view элемент?

Tags: android, button, view, android-view, android-button

У меня есть переменная с `view элементом (кнопкой)` как её клонировать чтоб загнать в `ArrayList` ?

Comment: Какова ваша конечная цель? Добавить на экран идентичную кнопку или обращаться к текущей через ArrayList?

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ Клонировать несколько кнопок в ArrayList вывести их на экран и всячески потом каждую индивидуально изменять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, наилучшим способом будет загружать вьюху `LayoutInflater`-ом:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_to_load, null, false);
```

так у вас будет каждый раз создавать идентичная копия элемента, описанного в отдельном файле разметки

Answer (score 0):

Реализация сериализации `View` не выгодное решение по ресурсам (быстрее спарсить XML).
Для оптимизации времени исполнения и при необходимости разгрузки UI потока  рекомендую использовать [`AsyncLayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.html), обернув `inflate()` в новый поток.